# Regex - match a string without leading and trailing spaces

Tags: regex, string, language-agnostic

Building an expression that will reject an untrimmed input string.

Have a group of white-listed symbols, including *whitespace*. But it cannot be used at the first or at the last one position. However, it may be used between any leading and trimming white-listed symbol in any amount.

Have a following expression:

```
^[^\s][A-Za-z0-9\s]*[^\s]$
```

... but it doesn't work in several reasons, at least it still matches at leading and trailing position any non-whitespace symbol even if it's not white-listed. Futhermore, it won't match single letter word even if it matches to the expression.

The whitelist is A-Z, a-z, 0-9, whitespace.

Valid case:

```
Abc132 3sdfas // everything ok
```

Invalid case #1:

```
 asd dsadas // leading\trailing space is exist
```

Invalid case #2:

```
$das dsfds // not whitelisted symbol at the leading\trailing position
```

So, how to add a whitespace symbol to the white-list if it isn't the leading or the trailing symbol?

Comment: Could you make some examples of both **valid** and **invalid** cases?

Comment: try using \\s please let me know if that helped, I had same issue and it was what i was missing

Comment: @MaskedMan, yeah, take a look

Comment: `^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\s+[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$`

Comment: `^[A-Za-z0-9]+.*[A-Za-z0-9]+$`: first character should be `alphanumeric` and at least has one occurrence, and the last also should be the same, with everything in between.
**Does it solve the problem?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use lookarounds to ensure that there are no spaces at both ends:

```
^(?! )[A-Za-z0-9 ]*(?<! )$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/kX4oF6/1)

But if the environment doesn't support lookarounds the following regex works in most engines:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?: +[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$
```

Comment: Aren't the look-ahead (?!...) and look-behind (?<!...) assertions the wrong way round?

Comment: How could you do it in Firefox, which doesn't support look-behind?

Comment: @DenisHowe No they are not the wrong way around. You could use `^(?! |.* $)[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$` in JS or see the update.

Comment: does not detect string some@something.com

Comment: @YousafRaza because it wasn't OP's requirement?!

Comment: /^[^ ].*[^ ]$/
@revo can you update your answer? following is a regex that only disables spaces at the start and at the end of string

Comment: @YousafRaza sorry no. Because question specified a whitelist of characters. If I do `.*` then I broke it.

Comment: Can we get to update the question title accordingly?

Answer (score 3):

depending on your regex engine supporting look around

```
^(?=[A-Za-z0-9])([A-Za-z0-9\s]*)(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/389)