# Regular expression to only allow letters and space in input filed but the first character should not be space

Tags: javascript, regex

New to regex. I am validating a input filed. I need to write regular expression which checks the following:
Only letters and spaces are allowed not numbers and special charactes
The first character should be a valid letter [a-zA-Z] not a space.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: You may find [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38935454/4362829) useful. If you have any specific problems that are giving you trouble, post details and I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Thanks Tim but that link didn't help

Comment: Perhaps `^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z ]*$`

Answer (score 0):

The following regex accepts only letters or spaces as you wanted.

```
^(?! )[A-Za-z\s]*$
```

Quick explanation:

`^` Matches beginning of input

`(?! )` Zero-width negative look-ahead assertion a.k.a. "not followed by...", so the first letter won't be a space character

`[A-Za-z\s]*` Accept only letters (A-Za-z) and spaces (\s) any time (*)

`$` Matches end of input

**Edit**: If you don't want to match an empty string, then need to accept at least one character instead of any : `^(?! )[A-Za-z\s]+$`

Comment: `The first character should be a valid letter [a-zA-Z] not a space`, your regex will also match an empty string.

Comment: @Thefourthbird (?! ) means that the first character can't be a space. Also, if you don't want to match an empty string, you can change * for + so it will have at least one letter, but the original poster did not ask for this.